# Common graphics file folder for multiple articles

Tags: graphics, miktex, texmaker, windows, include

I prepare my presentations for various lectures and typically, they share the graphic files (.png).
What is the best way to store them once and have access from several .tex files in different folders?
Is there any default folder for the latex (miktex, texamker) to share graphics (on Windows)?

Comment: `\graphicspath{{c:/my/repository/of/graphics/files}}` (in the document preamble)

Comment: Either do as Alex suggests, or look in the MikTeX manual: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console, see the section _Registering a user-managed TEXMF root directory_

Comment: cool, both seem straightforward and clear, I will test.

Comment: @AlexG your solution worked fine, though I needed to add "/" at the ens of path. Also - how can I make the relative path, so that solution is portable between my machines?

Comment: A relative path does not contain neither drive letter nor leading slash. Then, the given path is relative to the current folder and must be reachable from all your project folders in the same way. Not sure if such a path may start with `../` in order to go upwards on level to reach non-subfolders.

Comment: Corrected `\graphicspath` usage: `\graphicspath{{c:/my/repository/of/graphics/files/}}`